# What is this DFN 8-pin package?

Tags: identification, packages, dfn

Can anyone identify this 8-pin DFN SMD component?

Marking is:

```
LAAS
N819
417
```

[image]

Comment: That's DFN, not QFN.

Comment: From what device/module did you get it?

Comment: Components around it may provide clues so please post a wider shot

Comment: Diana - Hi, You posted an answer to say thank you. Although that's polite, Stack Exchange has different rules from typical forums (please see the [tour] & [help]). An *answer* cannot be used in that way, so it was deleted (and moved to a comment, at least temporarily). Please see the article in the [help] called: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers)". If your question has been solved, consider upvoting useful answers & consider [áccepting](/help/accepted-answer) your choice of best answer, when you're sure it answers your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly Analog Devices [LTC1540](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1540fb.pdf).

The LTC1540 is an 8-pin DFN package, size 3x3mm. The datasheet indicates the first line of the marking should be LAAS:

[image: Pin Configuration and Marking from Datasheet]

With no further details about what the circuit does and he surrounding components and dimensions, this is purely a best guess.

It seems promising as pins 1 and 2 (V- and GND) appear to go to a large plane from your image, and pin 7 (V+) goes to a thick trace which could be a power feed.

Comment: Pin n°1 marking is typical of Linear Tech (Analog devices) +1

Comment: Wow thanks for the suggestion. Looks matching base on marking.
Will still verify the connections. Thanks alot! It was a great help =)